# what do i do about the PIL import not working

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, python-imaging-library

i have downloaded pillow and tried to use `from PIL import ImageTk, Image` but it says that PIL is an unresolved reference and I don't know why or what to do about it. I used `pip freeze` in the terminal and it says that its downloaded. I am using pycharm and I have ticked both the buttons under configure interpreter section. I don't know what else to try

Comment: _but it says that PIL is an unresolved reference_ Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: Would appreciate marking an answer, to close this Q